# django javascript redirect to a link on initial

Tags: javascript, django

In my template `sometemplate.html` I have a code like:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}" >Sign in using Facebook</a>
```

When this page loads I want to show authenticating message and would like to redirect to this link. 
How can I do this in javascript plz help.

Answer (score 0):

sometemplate.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        alert('Here you show a popup with some message');
        window.location.replace("{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}");
    })();       
</script>
```

or if you want to use jquery, then:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert('Here you show a popup with some message');
        window.location.replace("{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}");
    });       
</script>
```

instead of `alert()`, you should do some more handsome popup.

hope, this helps

Comment: I want to redirect it with in facebook. I am makeing canvas app

Comment: what if I want to pass a dynamic value from javascript? `window.location.replace("{% url 'url_name' 'variable' %}");`?